# How to display count in view from a different controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I changed the Person controller and Home view.
I have 209 people in the database. And that's how it shows me in the Person view.
When I interrupt the code count shows me 0.

View Home:
I also made changes here.

```
 @model Legolandia.Models.Store    
    @{    
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    }

    <div class="jumbotron">

    <div class="row">
     @section Scripts {
    <script>
// document.ready is fired once the page has loaded in the browser
$(document).ready(function () {
    // set the url to get the data from the PersonController
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetPersonCount", "Person")';

    // use jQuery.getJSON to get our data from the controller
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        // update the element with the count from the controller
        $('#personCount').text(data.count);
    });
});
    </script>
}
        <div id="orange" class="col-md-4">
            <a class="change-a" href="/Person/Index">

                <div class="change-title">
                  Person in system: <span id="personCount"></span>
                </div>
```

Controller Person:

I also made changes here.

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Legolandia.Models;

    namespace Legolandia.Controllers
    {
        public class PersonController : Controller
        {
            private LegolandEntities db = new LegolandEntities();

            // GET: Person  

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                var person = db.Person.Include(o => o.xxx);
                ViewBag.PersonCount = db.Person.Count();
                return View(person.ToList());
            }

   public ActionResult GetPersonCount()
        {
            var count = db.Person.Count();  // get count from database
            var data = new { count };       // anonymous type
            return Json(data);              // return serialized Json data
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't save changes.  But still, it doesn't work. In Person/Index.cshtml I use: "In system:  @Model.Count(). And it work.

Comment: Can you confirm jQuery has been added to your site?  Can you confirm you don't get any errors (javascript and C#)?

Comment: I don't have any information about errors.

Comment: To see javascript errors open the browser debugger (press F12 when you're on 'Home/index') and go to the console to see errors.

Comment: You were right. The problem was with: "JsonRequestBehavior. AllowGet does not work with HttpGet".
I changed in the controller to: "return Json (data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
Now everything works. Thank you very much for your help. You are great.

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad you got it working!

Comment: @haldo 
You are the best programmer in the world ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to get data from `PersonController` and display it in a view of `HomeController`, I'd suggest using Ajax.

Create a new method in `PersonController` to return the data you need.  This method will return Json data which you can use in the view.

```
public ActionResult GetPersonCount()
{
    var count = db.Person.Count();  // get count from database
    var data = new { count };       // anonymous type
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  // return serialized Json data
}
```

Note: If you're using .Net Core you don't need the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` in the Json result.

Now, in `Home/Index.cshml` you will need to add some JavaScript.  I'll actually use jQuery since it makes this task a little easier.  Make sure you include jQuery on the page (MVC comes with jQuery included these days).

First, in `Home/index.cshtml` create a `<span>` element which will hold the value for `PersonCount`:

```
<div class="change-title">
    Person in system: <span id="personCount"></span>
</div>
```

Now, near the bottom of `Home/index.cshtml` add some script tags:

```
@section Scripts {
<script>
    // document.ready is fired once the page has loaded in the browser
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // set the url to get the data from the PersonController
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetPersonCount", "Person")';

        // use jQuery.getJSON to get our data from the controller
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            // update the element with the count from the controller
            $('#personCount').text(data.count);
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Finally, in `_Layout.cshtml` make sure you put `@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)` near the bottom of the page (below `@RenderBody()`).

Here I have used [`$.getJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).  It performs an ajax request to `Person/GetPersonCount`.  Then we update the `<span>` with the person count from the `GetPersonCount` in `PersonController`.

Here's the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me:

```
ViewBag.PatientCount = (from x in Hasta.TblPatient select x).Count();
```

Answer (score -1):

In your controller, save count in `ViewData`:

```c#
{
   ViewData["Users"] = _userManager.Users.Count();
   
   return View();
}
```

In your view, retrieve the value:

```razor
@Html.ViewData["Users"]
```